# Deleting XML using a selected Xpath and a for loop

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, xmldocument

I currently have the following code:

```
XPathNodeIterator theNodes = theNav.Select(theXPath.ToString());

while (theNodes.MoveNext())
{
    //some attempts i though were close
    //theNodes.RemoveChild(theNodes.Current.OuterXml);
    //theNodes.Current.DeleteSelf();
}
```

I have set xpath to what I want to return in xml and I want to delete everything that is looped. I have tried a few ways of deleting the information but it does't like my syntax. I found an example on Microsoft support: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317666 but I would like to use this while instead of a for each.

Any comments or questions are appreciated.

Comment: how to properly remove all the elements returned by the xpath (tags and all)

Comment: XPathNodeIterator does not have `RemoveChild` as a method and [it should not be modified directly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnodeiterator.current.aspx). Is there a reason you need a while loop? Using XDocument as @Alex-Aza suggests is functionally the same as what you are asking for.

Comment: as i mentioned in the comment before i cant seem to include it in my project -- not sure why not

Comment: @Johnston I went to your profile and saw this question at the top and thought it was a recent one but now I see you just made a couple minor edits a couple days ago

Comment: @Johnston once we comment back and forward enough there is a link that says Shall continue this in chat, then we click it and it opens a chat

Comment: @Beef That sounds good. I think theres alot we can talk about

Comment: @Johnston eventually once we comment enough back and forward I think it gives one of us the option to say let us continue this in chat

Comment: @Beef when do i see the chat thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string nodeXPath = "your x path";

XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load(/*your file path*/);

XmlNode node = document.SelectSingleNode(nodeXPath);
node.RemoveAll();

XmlNode parentnode = node.ParentNode;
parentnode.RemoveChild(node);
document.Save("File Path");
```

Comment: Why not to do just `node.RemoveAll();`?

Comment: @Bibhu: The same answer is predefined here. @Alex: node.RemoveAll(); it will remove all child nodes, but it will also remove all node' attributes.

Comment: @Alex Aza & Jalal Aldeen Saa'd   - I think "Johnston" wants to delete the parent node also so it will be better to use node.RemoveAll();

Comment: yes i do want to remove the parent node .. i like this way except it only deletes the element selected in my xpath .. i want to delete the parent which will also remove the children

Comment: so i just have my parent remaining..is there a way to do this in the removeAll includeing parent?

Answer (score 6):

Why not to use `XDocument`?

```
var xmlText = "<Elements><Element1 /><Element2 /></Elements>";
var document = XDocument.Parse(xmlText);

var element = document.XPathSelectElement("Elements/Element1");
element.Remove();

var result = document.ToString();
```

`result` will be `<Elements><Element2 /></Elements>`.

Or:

```
var document = XDocument.Load(fileName);

var element = document.XPathSelectElement("Elements/Element1");
element.Remove();

document.Savel(fileName);
```

**[Edit]** For .NET 2, you can use `XmlDocument`:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load(fileName);

XmlNode node = document.SelectSingleNode("Elements/Element1");
node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);

document.Save(fileName);
```

**[EDIT]**

If you need to remove all child elements and attributes:

```
XmlNode node = document.SelectSingleNode("Elements");
node.RemoveAll();
```

If you need to keep attributes, but delete elements:

```
XmlNode node = document.SelectSingleNode("Elements");
foreach (XmlNode childNode in node.ChildNodes)
    node.RemoveChild(childNode);
```

Comment: I cant see, to get the using to work (System.Xml.Linq.XDocument) errors out not being able to find it

Comment: I just thougth that there would b an easy way to delete everthing with how i already have it set up..it prints perfectly

Comment: @Johnston - what version of .NET are you using?

Comment: @Alex 2.0 is what its target is in my settings

Comment: @Johnston - it's kind of good to specify .net version in the question. Updated the answer.

Comment: @Johnston - out of curiosity, what was the judgement when you selected the answer? I though I provided more examples and details, didn't I? Is it personal? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `XmlDocument`:

```
string nodeXPath = "your x path";

XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load(/*your file path*/);//or document.LoadXml(...

XmlNode node = document.SelectSingleNode(nodeXPath);

if (node.HasChildNodes)
{
    //note that you can use node.RemoveAll(); it will remove all child nodes, but it will also remove all node' attributes.

    for (int childNodeIndex = 0; childNodeIndex < node.ChildNodes.Count; childNodeIndex++)
    {
        node.RemoveChild(node.ChildNodes[childNodeIndex]);
    }
}

document.Save("your file path"));
```